# How to disable visual from being selected but show tooltip on mouseover?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a table and a chart visual.

When user clicks on table cell or bar chart, the other visuals get filtered/highlighted. I know this can be disabled using the edit interactions setting.

However I am interested in preventing the user from being able to click on the cell or bar. Is there any setting to achieve this?

Note that I still want the user to be able to mouse over and see the tooltip.

Comment: No, there is not setting to make the visual static, you can just reduce the interaction as you mentioned, but you'll still be able to select stuff, it will just apply to that visual.

Answer (score 1):

Simply insert and overlay a 100% transparent shape (like rectangle) over the visual.